# Google Street View for iOS with device orientation / gyroscope sensor

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, core-motion

Is there an easy way to make in iOS Google Street View `GMSPanormaView`'s camera  follow the device's orientation via data from its motion sensors?

If not, has anyone already done it and can share a code snippet that takes data from `CoreMotion`, maybe manipulates it to create `GMSPanoramaCamera`, and passes it to the `GMSPanoramaView` with `animateToCamera:animationDuration:`?

Any relevant Android code would also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Upon checking the [Maps SDK for iOS:Internal: Street View](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/streetview), there is no built-in function/implementation for the device orientation/ gyroscope sensor.

According to [Ziem's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29878306/5995040) answer you can try implement this by yourself(create function). He also give pointers to study the following:

> - [Set the camera orientation point of view](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/streetview#animate_the_camera_movements)
> - [Animate the camera movements](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/streetview#animate_the_camera_movements)

Reference:

- [Blog](http://dev.topheman.com/tag/gyroscope-accelerometer/)
- [Github](https://github.com/topheman/PanoramaSensorsViewer)

> Using a site they have successfully create a function that will let you browse the Google streetview panoramas with your smartphone/tablet like you were inside it, just by moving your phone like a window to the world.